# iPhone 4S text message annoyance

Tags: ios

I updated my iPhone 4S to iOS 9, but now "0:00" appears sometimes in the text message window. Am I doing something to cause that to appear?

Comment: I have been having the same problem. Turning off the phone and on does work, but it appears again after a few messages. Can't figure out what setting to change.

Comment: Go to settings -> messages and turn off raise to listen. I could reproduce the error until I switched that off.

Comment: iOS 9.1 supposedly fixes this; its in the release notes today and is available

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue since the betas of 9.0 and can confirm it up to 9.0.2.

The reason for the appearance of this issue is that the iPhone thinks you are trying to record a message. This occurs whenever the proximity sensor thinks that you have put your phone to your ear or otherwise been fooled into thinking so.

This feature works fine with iMessages, but SMS obviously does not support sending voice messages. Whatever the reason, it gets triggered but the software does not know how to handle it, leaving it in the inconsistent state.

A temporary solution is to quit the Messages app with the Multitasking switcher, or trigger a voice message in an iMessage conversation and cancel (which interestingly prevents the issue from reoccurring while the Messages app remains in memory).

The ultimate solution will have to come from Apple in a bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9.0.1 is out now. It's really all bug fixes for iOS 9.0. Go to Settings > General > Software Update and update your iPhone.

**Update:** iOS 9.0.2 is out now, so be sure to update to that.

Comment: I have updated to 9.0.1 and still having same issue.

Comment: @DarrellHarris Hopefully future updates will fix your issue, then.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same thing happen with my messaging as well. I turned the phone fully off and back on and it seemed to have solved it.  Good luck